# Android Removing Proximity Alert

Tags: android, alert, proximity

i am working on app which deals with proximity alerts. I can add proximity alert but I can not remove these proximity alerts. I have tried my code both on phone and virtual device but i couldn't manage to remove them.

Here is my code:

the activity where locations saved to database and proximity alerts added

```
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String title = titleText.getText().toString();
                        if(title.matches("")){
                            Toast.makeText(CurrentLocationActivity.this,"Please provide a Title",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            saveLocation(saveProximityAlertPoint(title));                                              
                            setResult(RESULT_OK);                                     
                            Toast.makeText(CurrentLocationActivity.this,"Location Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                        }
                    }
                });

    private void saveLocation(int unique_location_id) {
                if (location == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No last known location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return ;
                }
                else{
                    String title = titleText.getText().toString();                     
                    String type = typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();                                         
                    range = (int) (radius + POINT_RADIUS);      
                    int unique_id = unique_location_id;     
                    Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    Double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    location_id = mDbHelper.createLocation(title, type, range, unique_id, latitude, longitude);

                    titleText.setText("");
                    radiusBar.setProgress(0);
                }
            }

    private int saveProximityAlertPoint(String title) {
                if (location == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No last known location.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    Double latitudeProxAlert = location.getLatitude();
                    Double longitudeProxAlert = location.getLongitude();
                    int unique_location_id = addProximityAlert(latitudeProxAlert, longitudeProxAlert, title);

                    return unique_location_id;
                } 
            }

    private int addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, String title) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
                intent.putExtra(LOCAION_TITLE, title);

                PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ++pending_intent_unique_id , intent, 0);

                locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, range, PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, proximityIntent );

                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);  
                registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity has been added for " + title + " with unique_id " + pending_intent_unique_id,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("UNIQUEID", pending_intent_unique_id);
                editor.commit();
                return pending_intent_unique_id;
            }
```

and the other activity where i tried to remove proximity alerts

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {                  
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); 

                Cursor proxRemoveCursor = mDbHelper.fetchLocation(info.id);
                removeProximityAlert(proxRemoveCursor.getInt(proxRemoveCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_UNIQUE_LOCATION_ID)));

                mDbHelper.deleteLocation(info.id);

                proxRemoveCursor.close();

                return true;
}

    private void removeProximityAlert(int unique_id) {

            String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);

            Intent anIntent = new Intent(REMOVE_PROXIMITY);
            PendingIntent operation = 
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), unique_id , anIntent, 0);
            locationManager.removeProximityAlert(operation);
        }
        }
```

It's a little bit long code but that's the shortest way to put my question right. Thnx for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! The problem is that the actions I was sending to intent objects on `addProximityAlert()` and `removeProximityAlert()` wasn't matching. Now I can remove proximity alerts after correcting my mistake.

Comment: Can you show your final code so I can see how you solved your problem please?

Comment: Intent anIntent = new Intent(REMOVE_PROXIMITY); Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);. my final code is there. problem is; REMOVE_PROXIMITY and PROX_ALERT_INTENT should match. When i first tried it they were different. When they are same you can remove the proximity alert.

Comment: Cheers for replying to me, I have spent weeks trying to fix this!

Comment: I still do not know what you mean by match, I have tried this all day, could you edit your question to show your final code please as I have tried everything. Thank you!

Comment: when you are creating you give an id to intent. if you add a proximity alert with an id you should remove it with that specific id given. so in this case PROX_ALERT_INTENT(an integer value) and REMOVE_PROXIMITY(an integer also) should be the same.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, can I send you my code to look at because it looks right but doesn't work, all I need you to look at is the add and remove proximity alert methods and how I call them. If you could that would be great, so far you are the only person I have seen on SO that has fixed this problem. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: My final code is there and sorry that i am busy right now and can't look at your code. when adding a proximity alert as this PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), uniqueId , intent, 0);
  locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, range, PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, proximityIntent ); you are giving a pending intent. when removing this pending intent should be same as it has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Which is the value of REMOVE_PROXIMITY?