# How to store data from SQLite in a 2D Arraylist?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I need to get all of the information from my SQLite Database and store it in an Array List, or some other way if there is a better way. My database has 6 columns, here is how I am attempting to extract the data and store it in an Arraylist index;

```
db.open();
    for(int i = 0; i<= amount; i++)
    {

        Cursor c = db.fetchAllNotes();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {      
                mid = c.getString(0);
                place =c.getString(1);
                info =c.getString(2);
                coordl1 =c.getString(3);
                coordl2 =c.getString(4);
                colour =c.getString(5);

                 //code here to store each string in an Array index
                mapSetupList.add(mid,place,info,coordl1,coordl2,colour);

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    db.close();
```

I know how to create an Array list, but I do not know how to store 6 strings in one index, I experimented with 2D Arraylists, but this seemed to be too complicated and I didn't think it was the right way to do it. Is there a better way to do this, if not how can this be done with Arraylists?

Comment: now i wrote answer, it took little more time.

Comment: I am going to try your answer it looks a little complicated, but I will give it a good try! Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to create one own defined Object that will wrap all columns as properties?

```
public class Foo {

   private int id; // alternative to id column in db
   private String type;
   private String date;
   ...

   public void setId(int id) { // setter
      this.id = id;
   }

   public int getId() { // getter
      return this.id;
   }
}
```

Then create `ArrayList<Foo>` and now you can simply save data from **SQLite** into ArrayList:

```
public void store() {
   Cursor c = null; // first declare and initialise appropriate objects
   ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
   Foo member = null;
   try {
      c = db.rawQuery(query, whereArgs); // perform query
      if (c.moveToFirst()) { // move cursor to first row because implicitly
         do { // cursor is position before first row
            member = new Foo(); // for each row create new Foo
            member.setId(c.getInt(0)); // initialise properties
            member.setType(c.getString(1));
            member.setDate(c.getString(2));
            ...
            foos.add(member); // add Foo into ArrayList
         } while (c.moveToNext()); // it moves cursor to next row
      }
   }
   finally { // in finally block release datasource(s), cursor(s)
      if (c != null) {
         c.close();
      }
      if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
         db.close();
      }
   }
}
```

**Note:** I recommend this approach. It's clear, safe and effective. Don't forget to release any datasources, cursors after work is done to avoid usually thrown exceptions like cursor is already open, database is already closed etc.

### Update:

> I am unsure about the class example, with the defined object and
>   getters and setters, can you please elaborate before I try this? Thank
>   you!!

So getters and setters are methods which are used "generaly "for manipulating with properies of Object to preserve **Encapsulation** - very important thing in OOP. Setters are used for initialising properties and getters for getting properties of Object.

Now i wrote for you example of method for store data from sqlite into ArrayList. There is this line:

```
member.setId(c.getInt(0));
```

where `setId(c.getInt(0))` is setter of **Foo Object** with one Integer as parameter and with this method now you will fill up id value with data from `Cursor`.

Comment: I do like the sound of clear, safe and effective! :) I am unsure about the class example, with the defined object and getters and setters, can you please elaborate before I try this? Thank you!!

Comment: @deucalion0 wait for a while.

Comment: @deucalion0 i updated question and add also comments on more important lines with explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look at this now and take my time to try this, Thanks again!

Comment: That worked great, thank you for the professional approach and detailed explanation, to an overall great answer to my question! sajmon_d, you seem to have great knowledge of android, what would be the correct way to ask you to look at another question of mine, I do not know if this is allowed on SO. Thank you again!!!!

Comment: @deucalion0 O_o many thanks also for beautiful words which are well listen :) normally if i will see your question i will try to reply.

Comment: Salmon_d I have been trying to solve this problem for over two weeks, here is my SO question if you have time maybe you can have a look? Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323848/proximity-alerts-keep-being-added-how-to-remove-them-by-using-ids

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class that contains all the informations that you like, and then create an instance of it then add that instance to the ArrayList.

Comment: That is exactly my aim!!! I just do not know how to do this, any advice on how to write the code? Thank you!